# How to characterize z-indexing for the DOM? (2)

Tags: javascript, dom, z-index

I've been a bit care-less with choosing z-indexes in my CSS.

I'd like to traverse the DOM and report all the z-indexes with their respective ID's.

For example:

```
id           z-index
header       10
main         0
menu         20
```

The end result would be an object whose keys are the element id and the value is the z-index.  One might call it `z_obj`

```
// pseudo code

var z_obj = {el_id: el_zindex};
```

Getting the z-index for each element ( `el` ) should be easy using something like `filter` and the code below:

```
// attr is attribute
data = _.filter(el.attributes, function (attr) {
    return (/^z-index/).test(atttr.name);
});
```

But how would I traverse the DOM to get all z-indexes and store that in an object?

I'd like to do this w/ out libraries, and using the code above if possible.

This would be a good debug tool in general.

Comment: Get all elements with `document.getElementsByTagName("*")`, iterate over the collection with a `for` loop, and use `window.getComputedStyle()` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle ) to get its currently applied style. You can retrieve the `z-index` property from there

Comment: In this case, it just means "all" tagnames

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/S8GW3/ . Note that I used `document.body` so that it only gets elements within the `<body>`

Comment: I don't think it's a useful tool for debugging z-inidices. a) not all z-indexed elements have an id b) It's lacking the stacking context of the elements. [z-indices are relative to the closest positioned element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index), so a `z-index:9999` could be shown below a `z-index:15` depending on the nesting of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all elements with [`getElementsByTagName("*")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName), iterate over the collection with a `for` loop, and use [`window.getComputedStyle(Node)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle). From there, you can retrieve the `z-index`. Here's an example:

```
var zObj, allEls, i, j, cur, style, zIndex;

zObj = {};
allEls = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (i = 0, j = allEls.length; i < j; i++) {
    cur = allEls[i];
    style = getComputedStyle(cur);
    zIndex = style.getPropertyValue("z-index");
    zObj[cur.id] = zIndex;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mj3cR/1/

Where `zObj` is an Object, keys represented by the `id` attributes, and values represented by the `z-index` style.

Note that `getComputedStyle` is not supported in IE < 9, but of course there are [many polyfills](http://www.google.com/?q=javascript+getcomputedstyle+polyfill) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
reportZ = function () {
    var z_arr = {},
        all_el = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*"),
        i,
        len,
        cur,
        style,
        z_index;
    for (i = 0, len = all_el.length; i < len; i++) {
        cur = all_el[i];
        style = win.getComputedStyle(cur);
        z_index = style.getPropertyValue("z-index");
        if (z_index !== "auto") {
            z_arr[i] = [cur.id, cur.tagName, cur.className, z_index];
        }
    }
    return z_arr;
};
```

Comment: I guess you wanted `var z_arr = []`?

Comment: Nope, I tried that first, but than you have a bunch of indices that point to nothing.  If you use an object literal, the in-betweens are not populated.  Much easier to read.  Also, interesting to see how the elements are indexed by the DOM and to quantify how many elements there are on the page.

Comment: Ah, I see where you go, though a sparse array wouldn't have been worse. However, as the numeric indices have no meaning, a dense array (with `z_arr.push()`) would have been better. At least, you shouldn't use "arr" in a variable name for an object :-)